# Getting output with html tag

Tags: html, mysql, web, tags, web-deployment

In my mysql db i have stored few data like

```
 Name
```

or

```
Surname
```

etc. I want them to be bold and italic while viewed in html page. But whenever I am fetching data from database it shows literally. No html tags are being processed. I have tried every datatype even BLOB. I have even tried changing utf unicode. But nothing solves my problem. Please help.

Comment: post some code, please.....

Comment: Please include the code you are using to output the value from the database to the HTML.

Comment: It sounds like you're escaping your output as HTML. Stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code being used it's hard to say but if you're using PHP to interface with the database I think [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is probably being used to sanitize the data either when it's stored or retrieved from the database.

As a result of this no HTML tags which may be stored in the data will remain when they are output into the document.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I believe the manipulation should be done after getting the fields from the database. 
But you may also want to try storing the data with the HTML tags into the Database.
For example:

`<strong> Text </strong>`